# Removing all slashes at the end of the url

Tags: nginx

I am trying to remove any trailing slashes from the url. This works everywhere except the homepage.

Here's where it works:

- sub.example.com/ => sub.example.com
- sub.example.com/test/ => sub.example.com/test
- sub.example.com/test/// => sub.example.com/test

Here's where it doesn't work:

- sub.example.com/// => sub.example.com///

My config file:

```
server {
    server_name sub.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/;
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;

    #SSL settings
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand something from my explanation, you can re-ask your question on the SO in Russian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't understand some very important parts going under the hood.

**1. HTTP [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request can't contain an empty string as a path.**

When you type `sub.example.com/` at your browser address bar, it is a browser who hides a trailing slash. This is applied only for the root requests, in any other case (including `sub.example.com//`, `sub.example.com/test/`, `sub.example.com/test//`, etc.) you'll see the full path at the address bar. No matter if you type that slash or not, HTTP request issued by the browser will look like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: sub.example.com
...
```

**2. `rewrite` nginx directive works with the *normalized* URI.**

Both `location` and `rewrite` directive works with so-called [*normalized*](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#:%7E:text=The%20matching%20is%20performed%20against%20a%20normalized%20URI) URIs:

> The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash.

That means, for all the requests like `sub.example.com/test/`, `sub.example.com/test//`, `sub.example.com/test///`, etc., nginx see the normalized request URI as `/test/` (that's the reason your rewrite rule works in a single step rather than the four-step `sub.example.com/test///` -> `sub.example.com/test//` -> `sub.example.com/test/` -> `sub.example.com/test` loop).

And the same is true for any of the `sub.example.com/`, `sub.example.com//`, `sub.example.com///`, etc. requests, the normalized URI will be seen by nginx as `/` making any rewrite rule unusable.

However, slashes compression can be turned off using the [`merge_slashes`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes) directive (read the security considerations). And to prevent multiply redirects where each redirect removes only a single trailing slash, use a non-greedy `*` and a greedy `+` [quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) for your regex pattern:

```
merge_slashes off;
rewrite ^(/.*?)/+$ $1 permanent;
```

Comment: I understand) Now everything is clear to me. But I didnt find what the consequences will be if I turn off merge_slashes.

Comment: An excerpt from the docs: _Note that compression is essential for the correct matching of prefix string and regular expression locations. Without it, the `//scripts/one.php` request would not match `location /scripts/ { ... }` and might be processed as a static file._ (revealing `one.php` source code to the user instead of executing it).